# Add middleware to pusher channel in laravel

Tags: laravel, websocket, middleware, pusher

So I made a little chat functionality in laravel using pusher so it updates in real time. I have an event with the following methods I call using `broadcast(new MessageSent($message, $conversationId));` whenever a message is sent.

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return ['chat-' . $this->conversationId];
}

public function broadcastAs()
{
    return 'new-message';
}
```

And a piece of js pushing it to my frontend that gets called like this

```
var channel = pusher.subscribe('chat-' + {{ $conversation->id }});

channel.bind('new-message', function(data) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    pushForeignMessage(data.message);
});
```

It works just as expected, but I have no idea how I can make it so that not everyone can just listen to chat-number and see every new message that gets sent. I already have some middleware for it, but I have no clue how to make it so that you can only listen to a specific channel if it is true for that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I used laravel Echo for this, which makes it simpler so you don't have to write your own auth entrypoint.

I also just returned true or false depending on some method in a model which checks everything I need.

```
Broadcast::channel('private-chat-{conversationId}', function ($user, $conversationId) {
    if(!Model::HasAccess){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

And make sure you return a private channel in your event.

```
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('private-chat-' . $this->conversationId);
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'new.message';
    }
```

And the Echo code looks like this. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting#client-pusher-channels for a quick setup.

```
Echo.private('private-chat-{{ $conversation->id }}')
            .listen('.new.message', (e) => {
                pushForeignMessage(e.message);
            }).error(error => {
                console.error('Could not subscribe to chat: ' + error.error)
                window.errorMessage('Kon niet verbinden met de chat. U kan geen realtime berichten ontvangen.', 'danger')
            });
```

I am feeling this is kind of dirty, but it works and does what I need. If someone knows a better / easier or 'the laravel way' to do this, please tell me.